# Extract line which has a positive value in the particular column when its consecutive line has a negative value in the same column

Tags: awk

I am trying to perform some analysis on some raw datasets where I stuck in between to extract the particular line in which 9th column has a positive value and its consecutive line has a negative value in the same column.

File:

```
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  986   280    280
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  975   284    4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  968   284.4  0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  960   284    -0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  944   283    -1
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  925   284    1
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  901   286    2
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  892   286.8  0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  850   286    -0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  700   276.8  -9.2
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  677   275.2  -1.6
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  594   268.9  -6.3
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  587   269.1  0.2
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  507   260.1  -9
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  500   259.5  -0.6
```

In the above file line number 3 has a positive value in 9th column (0.4) and its consecutive line has a negative value (-0.4). So, I want to extract line 3. Similarly line 8 and line 13.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question(along with sample of expected output too in your question), which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @RaviderSingh13. I wrote really a big code for data analysis in which I couldn't able to apply coding skill for this point particularly. So I couldn't write anything particularly for this logic in my code and now I am seeking for help.

Comment: Please roll back this edit where you've added my posted answer in question. It will confuse future visitors that you already had this solution.

Comment: No, as I said your answer is very close to my effort. there is a missing term in my effort, which was (pr == $0;) at the last in your answer.

Comment: Oh.. yes, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by `extract`? Do you mean print the matching lines or remove (i.e. print everything except) the matching lines? Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk '$9 < 0 && p9 > 0 {print pr; pr = p9 = ""} $9 > 0 {pr = $0; p9 = $9}' file

2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  968   284.4  0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  892   286.8  0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  587   269.1  0.2
```

Or a more readable form:

```sh
awk '$9 < 0 && p9 > 0 {
   print pr
   pr = p9 = ""
}
$9 > 0 {
   pr = $0
   p9 = $9
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you @Anubhava. It works fine for me and very close to my effort.

Comment: Just a request that including your attempted code in question will always get you speedy and accurate help.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you. I will update my question with my effort.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant, could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($NF<0){
    arr[FNR]=$NF
  }
  next
}
($NF>0) && (arr[FNR+1]<0)
' Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                     ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  if($NF<0){                 ##Checking condition if last field is lesser than 0 then do following.
    arr[FNR]=$NF             ##Creating arr with index of current line number which has value as last field here.
  }
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($NF>0) && (arr[FNR+1]<0)    ##Checking if last field is greater than 0 AND array with index of current line number+1 is lesser than 0 then print current line.
' Input_file  Input_file     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

With samples output will be as follows.

```
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  968   284.4  0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  892   286.8  0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  587   269.1  0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '$NF<0 && p{print p; p=""} $NF>=0{p=$0}' file

2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  968   284.4  0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  892   286.8  0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  587   269.1  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  986   280    280
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  975   284    4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  968   284.4  0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  960   284    -0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  944   283    -1
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  925   284    1
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  901   286    2
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  892   286.8  0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  850   286    -0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  700   276.8  -9.2
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  677   275.2  -1.6
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  594   268.9  -6.3
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  587   269.1  0.2
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  507   260.1  -9
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  500   259.5  -0.6
```

then

```
awk '(prevvalue>0.0 && $9<0.0){print prevline}{prevvalue=$9;prevline=$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  968   284.4  0.4
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  892   286.8  0.8
2020  01  11  00  28.5833  77.2000  587   269.1  0.2
```

Explanation: I am exploiting default behavior of `AWK`. If variable was never mentioned so far, it defaults to zero when used in arithmetic comparison (`>`) therefore `prevvalue>0.0` is always false for first line. For every line where your condition is met I `print` previous line (`prevline`) and for every line I set `prevvalue` and `prevline`, to use in next line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Handles potential first line issue & does what you want & parameterizes the column number (the subject of this request makes it sound like parameterization of the column is desired):

```
awk -v col=9 'FNR>1 && $(col)<0 && prev_col>=0 { print prev_line } { prev_col=$(col); prev_line=$0 }' file
```